# Where the performance delay will be happening application? Database? Citrix? To identify the performance delay 

Tags: database, powerbuilder, citrix

We are using citrix server for some applications which is developed from PowerBuilder. The problem is Performance delay. Last two months before we faced the same problem so our DBA team identified and we did the index in some table. The problem is repeating again today. But the Database side if we executes the same query which is in datawindow , it retrieves records 6 to 10 seconds, How can we identify the problem coming from where? Is this citrix server issue? or is this database issue? or is this PowerBuilder issue?

Please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough information here for us to even understand what kind of problem you're facing, let alone provide advice. (I'm not even clear if the quoted 6-10 seconds is the good reading or the bad... sounds bad to me.) We can throw out generic answers like application profiling and database tracing, but it sounds like you haven't even isolated the variables in your situation (e.g. does the performance change when you take out the Citrix element?), so we haven't much of a chance to comment precisely.

Comment: Our application is loading from Citrix, after loading that application, we are retrieving the customer information base on customer ID. At this time the data retrieval process getting delayed (45 seconds to 1+ minutes) How can we identify the issue cause?

Comment: Still not enough info, and it's really hard, if not impossible, to diagnose a performance problem without hands on. If you've got a problem with a network switch, we'll never be able to figure that out. I've pointed you a couple of the PB tools. You seem to think it is specifically the query (we haven't heard results from the PB tools that would verify this); you might want to ask the community around your DBMS (you haven't mentioned which one you're using) about what performance tools are available there. Beyond that, it's all about isolating components or behaviours and testing theories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of easy suggestions, how does the app perform NOT through Citrix?  Run it locally.

What is the difference in performance between Dev vs. Production?

Which DB?  The DBAs should be able to do a trace and see what SQL is being executed.

Comment: Yeah, I did that standalone application in Dev, We are using Oracle data base. it is working fine. But production has more data. So DBA team is now taken care those issue and re-indexed the table. So it is working - Thanks